# MVC 4 - How to conditionally disable this button?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I would like to conditionally disable this button, or hide it, if `Model.BicycleSellerListingId` is not greater than 0. Not sure how to do it.

```
<div style="position:absolute; left:300px; top:633px;">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", null, new { id = Model.BicycleSellerListingId }, FormMethod.Post))
    {
       <button type="submit">Delete Listing</button>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
<div style="position:absolute; left:300px; top:633px;">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", null, new { id = Model.BicycleSellerListingId }, FormMethod.Post))
{
   if(Model.BicycleSellerListingId < 0){
       <button type="submit">Delete Listing</button>
   }
}
</div>
```

OR

```
@if(Model.BicycleSellerListingId < 0){
    <div style="position:absolute; left:300px; top:633px;">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", null, new { id = Model.BicycleSellerListingId }, FormMethod.Post))
    {
       <button type="submit">Delete Listing</button>
    }
    </div>
}
```

OR

```
<div style="position:absolute; left:300px; top:633px;">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", null, new { id = Model.BicycleSellerListingId }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    <button type="submit"  @((Model.BicycleSellerListingId < 0) ? "disabled" : "")>Delete Listing</button>
}
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice and very simple. Simpler than I thought.