# How to disable a button with Razor?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

In my action I have

```
ViewBag.IsEnabled=false;
```

My view page has a button as follows.

```
@{string next = (bool)ViewBag.IsEnabled? string.Empty : "disabled" }
<button asp-action="Index" @next> Next </button>
```

But it does not work. How to fix it?

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/1962878.aspx?How+to+Disable+button+based+on+Model+value

Comment: `disabled="@next"` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247832/mvc-4-how-to-conditionally-disable-this-button

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem. missing disabled attribute:

```
@{string next = (bool)ViewBag.IsEnabled? string.Empty : "disabled='disabled'" }
<button asp-action="Index" "@next"> Next </button>
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Visual Studio or any other IDE?

Because it should point out your mistake.

Anyways, if you haven't figured it out already.

You missed a `';'.`

It should be:

```
@{string next = (bool)ViewBag.IsEnabled? string.Empty : "disabled"; }
```

Just tried it and it's working.